# Exchange Mailbox Delegate Access for a security group via EWS or PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, delegates, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Currently, I am able to add delegate security groups to a mailbox via Outlook by going to the Delegate Access section, finding the group, and setting the permission level.

I'd like to automate this, but have not found a way that works for groups.

The following PowerShell will add a group, but only set the folder permissions. It does not add the group as a delegate.

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "mailbox:\Calendar" -User "group" -AccessRights Editor
```

The following .NET EWS code will add user accounts exactly the way I want to add a group. If I add a group to the list, it will fail, yielding the following error: "The delegate does not map to a user in the Active Directory."

```
Public Function setEditor(mailbox As String, listDelegates As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)) As Boolean
    Dim setEditorResult As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim listDelUser As New List(Of DelegateUser)
        For Each strDelUser As String In listDelegates
            Dim delUser As DelegateUser = New DelegateUser(strDelUser)
            delUser.Permissions.CalendarFolderPermissionLevel = DelegateFolderPermissionLevel.Editor
            listDelUser.Add(delUser)
        Next
        Dim responses As Collection(Of DelegateUserResponse) = service.AddDelegates(New Mailbox(mailbox), MeetingRequestsDeliveryScope.NoForward, listDelUser)
        For Each response As DelegateUserResponse In responses
            If response.Result = 0 Then
                setEditorResult = True
            Else
                'log error
                Dim err As String = response.ErrorMessage
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        'log error
    End Try
    Return setEditorResult
End Function
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this that works for security groups? Thanks!

#### UPDATE 10/31/2014

I have found a way to add security groups as delegates and properly set their permissions.

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "MAILBOX" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo "DELEGATE"
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "MAILBOX:\Calendar" -User "DELEGATE" -AccessRights Editor
```

For multiple delegates, use the following:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "MAILBOX" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add="DELEGATE1","DELEGATE2"}
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "MAILBOX:\Calendar" -User "DELEGATE1" -AccessRights Editor
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "MAILBOX:\Calendar" -User "DELEGATE2" -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Unfortunately, I still have not been able to find a way to check the *Delegate receives copies of meeting-related messages sent to me.* checkbox for security groups.

Comment: After opening a case with Microsoft it looks like this is just not possible at the moment, both via PowerShell or EWS. It is a design limitation in both languages/APIs. I will follow up if I find other information that is relevant, but for now it looks like this is a manual process within Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to add security groups as delegates and properly set their permissions.

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "MAILBOX" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo "DELEGATE"
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "MAILBOX:\Calendar" -User "DELEGATE" -AccessRights Editor
```

For multiple delegates, use the following:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "MAILBOX" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{Add="DELEGATE1","DELEGATE2"}
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "MAILBOX:\Calendar" -User "DELEGATE1" -AccessRights Editor
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "MAILBOX:\Calendar" -User "DELEGATE2" -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Unfortunately, I still have not been able to find a way to check the Delegate receives copies of meeting-related messages sent to me. checkbox for security groups.

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you how to set the permissions by group with Add-Mailboxfolderpermission (i guess you cant) but you could use this to assign rights for all groupmembers:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "group" | % {Get-Mailbox $_.SamAccountName | Add-Mailboxfolderpermission -Identity "mailbox:\Calendar"
-AccessRights Editor}
```

This will cycle through all members in the group and assign them permissions on the mailboxfolder defined in the -Identity parameter.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, but this does not give delegate access, just access rights/permission.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the thread is already "old" by now, but I am working on a similar scenario and have an info that might interest you as well.

You are saying that:

"After opening a case with Microsoft it looks like this is just not possible at the moment, both via PowerShell or EWS. It is a design limitation in both languages/APIs. I will follow up if I find other information that is relevant, but for now it looks like this is a manual process within Outlook."

Not sure if what you mean above by design limitation refers only to security groups as per your specific scenario (well stated in the thread title), or if in general it's not possible to use PowerShell/ EWS to check "Delegate receives copies of meeting-related messages sent to me".

For the last part, I have found out an interesting EWS topic, check out:

[MeetingRequestsDeliveryScope enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.meetingrequestsdeliveryscope(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Searching a bit around, other Exchange folks already played with it, for instance last week someone wrote about this:

[Exploring Delegates with the EWS Managed API – Part I: The EWS Delegate Functions](http://sites.utexas.edu/glenmark/2014/12/27/exploring-delegates-with-the-ews-managed-api-part-i-the-ews-delegate-functions/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that was in reference to security groups only. The second link you provided actually confirms it as well. 

"They don’t work with delegation to groups, neither in terms of adding groups as delegates or displaying group delegates. Here is what we see running Get-EWSDelegates if a group has been set as one of the delegates."

We are actually in the process of filing a Design Change Request (DCR) with Microsoft. Who knows when it will happen, or if it ever will, but lets hope!